# Is boolean formula or circuit more powerful description than blackbox?

Tags: computational-complexity, boolean

Assume we are given boolean formula or circuit (I don't know if answer for this scenarios is different, and I am interested in both). Can we in polynomial time say anything about corresponding function that can't be said by using truth table as an oracle?

Formally, for some polynomial $p$ let $X$ be set of boolean functions that are realizable with boolean formula of size $p(n)$, where $n$ is number of variables.

Say that $O \subseteq X$ is oracle-polynomial if there exists a polynomial algorithm with oracle that separates $O$ from $X \setminus O$. For example, set of functions that are zero on all-zeroes assignment is oracle-polynomial, while set of constant functions is not.

Say that $F \subseteq X$ is formula-polynomial if there exists a polynomial algorithm that takes boolean formula of size at most $p(n)$ and decides if this formula defines function from $F$.

Clearly, $O \subseteq F$, as we can use formula as truth table oracle. Is converse true - does $O = F$?

My thoughts:

If $P = NP$ then answer is no: checking if formula defines constant function is co-NP, thus if $P = NP$ then set of non-constant function is formula-polynomial, but not oracle-polynomial.

If we further restrict set of formulas, for example require input to be DNF, then answer is again "no" - set of functions that are $1$ on exactly one assignment will be formula-polynomial, but not oracle-polynomial.

If instead of boolean formulas we consider algorithms (and oracle answers if algorithm stops in $n$ steps with some output) without restriction on time - the answer is "yes" by Rice's theorem (as we can decide only trivial set of function, so having code of algorithm doesn't help).

Answer (score 0):

No, the converse is not true.

Informally: Let $f$ be a formula that has a single satisfying assignment (it can be expressed with a formula of size $n$), and $g$ the always false formula.  You can separate $f$ from $g$ based on looking at the formula, but it takes exponentially many oracle queries to separate $f$ from $g$.  This result is unconditional (does not rely on the assumption that $P \ne NP$).

To be more precise/formal: let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of formulas that are a conjunction of $n$ clauses, where the $i$th clause has either the form $x_i$ or $\neg x_i$.  By construction, every formula in $f$ has a single satisfying assignment, and given the formula, it is easy to find the single satisfying assignment.  Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the singleton set of a single formula, the always-false formula.  An algorithm that can look at the formula can easily distinguish between $\mathcal{F}$ vs $\mathcal{G}$ (it is easy to recognize formulas in $\mathcal{F}$ or $\mathcal{G}$ from the formula itself).  But it is hard for an algorithm that only has oracle access to distinguish between $\mathcal{F}$ vs $\mathcal{G}$.  In particular, it takes exponentially many queries to distinguish between those two sets.  (Why?  Informally, because there are $2^n$ possible queries.  For $\mathcal{F}$, all but one of those $2^n$ inputs returns false; for $\mathcal{G}$, all inputs return false.  For $\mathcal{F}$, it takes exponentially many queries even to find a single query that returns true.)

Comment: How can we decide in polynomial time if arbitrary formula defines a function that has a single satisfying assignment? If UNAMBIGUOUS-SAT (separating always false sat-formulas from sat-formulas having exactly one satisfying assignment) is in $RP$, then $RP = NP$.

Comment: @mihaild, see edited answer for more explanation.  I propose a set of formula where it is easy to tell that it has a single satisfying assignment -- this is true by construction.  It's hard for general formula, but easy for the $F$ defined in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think it doesn't answer the question, or maybe I formulated it badly. We need an algorithm that takes arbitrary formula with size at most $p(n)$, and checks if this formula defines function from $F$. As your example (and note in my post) says, it is possible if we restrict formulas to some simple subsets, but question is what if we have no restrictions except size.